# How do I loop through files in a folder to get the max of a column in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of .csv files in a folder.  Each of them have the same format, with column B labeled "users_holding".  I would like to loop through this folder and print the max value of column B in each file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dirloc = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\folder"

for file in os.scandir(dirloc):
        if (file.path.endswith(".csv") or file.path.endswith(".pdf")) and file.is_file():
            a = pd.read_csv(file)

b = a['users_holding'].max()

print(b)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Happy to post more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

for file in os.listdir(dirloc):
    if (file.endswith(".csv") and os.path.isfile(file)):

        file_full_path = os.path.join(dirloc, file)
        df=pd.read_csv(file_full_path)

        #FINDING MAX value
        p=df['ColumnName'].max()

        print(p)
```

It will check for every `.csv` files and read them using `pandas` and will print max value out of a specific column using `.max()` function.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Good to hear that  @BradLee

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
for file in os.listdir(dirloc):
    if file.endswith(".csv") and os.path.isfile(file):
        file_full_path = os.path.join(dirloc, file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_full_path)
        print(df['users_holding'].max())
```

Comment: That is solving one issue - the read_csv part - but it is still not printing the max.

Comment: @BradLee please try now. Keep in mind that `read_csv` can't parse pdf files.